# Пробежать строки таблицы до определенной строки

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

Пытаюсь пропарсить таблицу excel с помощью OpenXmlSDK. Мне нужно получить все строки, начиная с 6-ой до строки "Обозначение типа амортизатора". Это все, что я нагуглил, но даже этот пример у меня не работает (видимо из-за значений самой таблицы). Мне бы рабочий пример чего-то подобного, чтобы разобраться, как пробежаться по строкам до определенной строки.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

string fileName = "test.xlsx";
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
            string text;
            foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
                foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    text = c.CellValue.Text;
                    Console.WriteLine(text + " ");
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Почему бы не сохранить эту таблицу изначально в CSV?

Comment: Допустим, а затем?

Comment: А затем легко распарсить ее с помощью CSVHelper или даже просто как текст.

Comment: При сохранении сохраняет только текущий лист, и потом у меня изначально на входе будут таблицы в формате .xlsx, а производиться действия с таблицами будут автоматически, каждый раз придется пересохранять.

Comment: Здесь, наверное, надо Linq запрос сделать, но линк для меня - это какая-то магия с бубнами.

Comment: Так сделайте так, чтобы на входе CSV было. Схематически Linq выглядеть может так `var rows = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Skip(5).TakeWhile(row => !row.Elements<Cell>().Any(cell => cell.CellValue.Text.Contains("Обозначение типа амортизатора"))` по `rows` можно запустить цикл `foreach` и обработать каждую.